# Call a function of another file using "exec" command from current file

Tags: php, function, arguments, exec, background-process

I have a file, `Notification.php`, which is a class. Its structure is like this:

```
Class Notificaiton
{
    public function sendNotification($token,$count)
    {
       // Here is the code for sending push notification(APNS)
    }      
}
```

Normally, if I want to call this function from another PHP file then I have to make an object of class and then call its method as below:

```
$notification = new Notification();   
$notification->sendNotification($token,$value);
```

But what I want to do is to call this in background process. So I used `exec()` command as below :

```
exec("/usr/bin/php /path/to/Notification.php >> /path/to/log_file.log 2>&1 &");
```

Here I wonder how can I call `function(sendNotificaiton())` of `file(Notification.php)` and pass arguments as parameter: $token and $count ?

Please guide me on this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Better include the file & call the function normally. It will be faster.

Comment: @user4035 : I am calling the function this way only(by including file).But here notification is taking time(around 3-5-7 seconds) to send.So it is not feasible.